# How to iterate thru a webform checkbox results

Tags: webforms

How do you iterate thru a webform checkbox array like so :

```
Checkboxes_name :
☒ option 1
☒ option 2
```

`[webform_submission:values:checkboxes_name_:value]` print :

```
option 1, option 2
```

I would like to have

```
- option 1
- option 2
```

I tried something like this and other variants, but no luck :

```
<ul{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:checkboxes_name_', webform_submission)}}>
  {% for item in webform_submission.values.checkboxes_name_ %}
    <li>{{ item.value }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use the Twig split function to covert the value into an array and then iterate that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this require a technical answer. We would need more informations about the template you're in.

Usually, when you experience this kind of difficulty to access or decorate data, it means you're at the wrong template level. Manually iterating on elements in a template is not the "Drupal Way".

The rendering engine will do it for you and provide a template name (suggestion, that you could see in the source code with the debug activated)

Check carefully the provided theme suggestions to choose the template in which the actual checkbox is rendered.

Override the template by using a more specific suggestion. Copy the code from the previously used template, you will have to the name and attributes of the checkbox element and it will be much easier to manage the display you want.

Comment: I need it to personnalise the body of a confirmation email sent after a submission form. This concern the webform>settings>Emails / Handlers. If there is another way could you please point me in which direction I should look for it?

Comment: I assume you're trying to do it in the twig template option of the mail handlers. I'm not sure it's the best place doing so. You may find info there https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2946976 or maybe look into a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail

Comment: Yes, I use twig I figured it was the easiest. Thanks for your new leads I will give it a try and keep you posted.